Clarifying what this prop means in nextjs with typescript
Currently going through the learn nextjs tutorial and am having a bit of trouble understanding why the props are structured like this. I am guessing that this has something to do with type script which I am not sure familiar with.
import Image from 'next/image';
import { UpdateInvoice, DeleteInvoice } from '@/app/ui/invoices/buttons';
import InvoiceStatus from '@/app/ui/invoices/status';
import { formatDateToLocal, formatCurrency } from '@/app/lib/utils';
import { fetchFilteredInvoices } from '@/app/lib/data';

// this line
export default async function InvoicesTable({ query, currentPage,}: { query: string; currentPage: number; }) {
  const invoices = await fetchFilteredInvoices(query, currentPage);

It looks like we are destructuring some variables (query, currentPage) and we are specifying the definition after colon. The definition is an object with 2 parameters, query of type string and currentPage with type number. Is this correct?
I think what's throwing me off a bit are the semicolons in the definition. I would expect a comma separating the parameters instead.
The nextjs docs don't really explain whats happening and I've done a bit of searching in the typescript docs but am still a bit unclear.

Yes, all you've said is correct. I agree with you and prefer to use commas rather than semi-colons in such cases, but it's a matter of style (see @stylistic/ts/member-delimiter-style for the ESLint rule) since both are valid.
